# Scroll Event Listener not getting replaced

Tags: javascript, function, events, scroll, dom-events

For the following pieces of code, dealing with fetching messages, based on pagination scrolling I believe.

```js
        function addScrollEvent(start, end, index) {

            console.log(start, end, index)

            function scroller() {
                if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
                    console.log(start, end, index)
                    // Fetch 100 more messages
                    container.innerHTML = '';
                    const moreMessages = jsonData.messages.slice(start, Math.min(end + 100, jsonData.messages.length));
                    moreMessages.forEach(createMessage);
                    end += 100;
                } else if (window.scrollY === 0) {

                    // Fetch 100 more messages
                    // console.log(jsonData.messages[start - 100]);
                    container.innerHTML = '';
                    const moreMessages = jsonData.messages.slice(Math.max(0, start - 100), end);
                    moreMessages.forEach(createMessage);
                    scrollToMessage(start);
                    start -= 100;
                };
            };

            // console.log(scroller)
            window.addEventListener('scrollend', scroller);
            currentScrollEvent = scroller;
        }

        function removeScrollEvent(func) {
            window.removeEventListener('scrollend', func);
        }
```

```js
            removeScrollEvent(currentScrollEvent); // currentScrollEvent is a global variable
            addScrollEvent(start, end, index);
```

I have called the same `addScrollEvent` function on two occasions, both with different start, end, and index values, yet it seems that the first event listener never got removed when I called the `removeScrollEvent` function, and the 2nd event listener i added, never runs, because the 1st event listener runs before it, what did i do wrong?